# Laravel Using template lateral in PHP file

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a custom API for data table from backend using PHP. In my objects, I need to pass in the dynamic HTML button syntax. I having trouble passing a string as a parameter because of the quote and double quote limitation. In javascript I can solve this problem by using template literal, is there anything similar I can use for PHP?

Here's my code ('I'm having trouble passing in the "Hello World")

```
$subdata = array();
$subdata[] = $shift->id;
$subdata[] = $shift->shift_name;
$sample_string = "Hello World"
$button = '';
$button .= '<button class="btn btn-default btn-smt fas fa-eye" data-placement="top" 
                 onclick="viewShiftDetails('.$shift->id.', '. $sample_string.')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="View Shift Details">
            </button>';

$subdata[] = $button;
return [$subdata];
```

Comment: try addslashes function: ```$button .= '<button class="btn btn-default btn-smt fas fa-eye" data-placement="top" 
                 onclick="viewShiftDetails('.$shift->id.', '. addslashes($sample_string).')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="View Shift Details">
            </button>';```

Comment: Hi there, it doesn't work, the quote is removed when it come to front end and now it assume my string is a variable

Comment: have you tried changing the double qoute to single qoute in `$sample_string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape your string using `\` as below:

**Change**

```
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-smt fas fa-eye" data-placement="top" 
                     onclick="viewShiftDetails('.$shift->id.', '. $sample_string.')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="View Shift Details">
                </button>'
```

**to**

```
   <button class="btn btn-default btn-smt fas fa-eye" data-placement="top" 
                     onclick="viewShiftDetails('.$shift->id.', \''. $sample_string.'\')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="View Shift Details">
                </button>'
```